# Rails unable to send id to update controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a blog application in which I am trying to have two links in that two links I am sending the post_id to my update controller but it is giving me error .And I want to collect that post_id  in my update controller and want to check the "status"(Status is basically the column name in my posts table and by default my status column has a status of pending ) .So when admin click on approve the status of column should change to approve and when admin click on decline the status of column should change to decline also  user post should be deleted .Admin can access all the users posts whereas user can access his only post

**posts_controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user! 

    def index
        @posts = Post.user_post(current_user).order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    end 

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def show    
        @post=find_params
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)           
        @post.user = current_user
        if @post.save
            Post.upload(params[:post][:files],@post.id)         
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @post = find_params
        puts "cccccccccc#{params[:commit]}"
    Post.up(@post.id,params[:commit])
    end

    def update
        @post = find_params


        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = find_params
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
        end

        def find_params
            Post.find(params[:id])
        end

end
```

**posts/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @post,html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="errors">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this post from saving:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :body %><br>

     <br>
     <!-- if you want to upload multiple files at a time -->
    <%= f.label :files %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :files,:multiple => true %><br>

    <br>


    <%= f.submit %>
    <br>

<% end %>
```

**posts/edit.html.erb**

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
    <h1>Edit Post</h1>

    <%= render 'form' %>
<br>


</div>
```

**migration**

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :status
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**posts/show.html.erb**

```
<div id="post_content">
    <h1 class="title"><%= @post.title %></h1>
    <p class="date">
        Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
         <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
          <%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

          <%= link_to "approve",[:edit,@post] %>
        <%= link_to "decline",[:edit,@post] %>

        <% end %>
    </p>
    <p class="body"><%= @post.body %></p>

    <div id="comments">
        <h2><%= @post.comments.count %> Comments</h2>
        <%= render @post.comments %>

        <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
        <%= render "comments/form" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 

    has_many :documents
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user

    validates :title, presence: true, length: {in: 5..15}
    validates :body,  presence: true,length: {in: 5..200}


    def self.up(id,params)
        puts "aaaaaaaa#{id}"
        puts "bbbbbbbbbbbbb#{params}"
    end 


    def self.user_post(id)
        role = User.find_role(id)
        if role == 'admin'
            Post.all

        elsif role == 'user'
            Post.where(user_id: id)

        elsif role == 'developer'
            Post.where(user_id: id)
        end             
    end

    def self.icon(extension)
        case extension
        when 'pdf'
                EXTENSION[1]['pdf']
        when 'png' || 'jpg' || 'jpeg'
            EXTENSION[0]['png']
        when 'doc' || 'odt'
            EXTENSION[2]['doc']
        end     

    end



####limit to upload files not more than ######
    def self.upload(files,post_id)  
        files.each do |file|    
        @file_extension=file.content_type.split('/')[1]         

            doc = Document.new(document: file,post_id: post_id )
            #save is a method which will save the content in the database 
            doc.save!
        end
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root "posts#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :uploads
end
```

Comment: I guess you should be using `@post.id` instead of `post.id` in your edit view..

Comment: Though it'll not work.. your code is... No Offence... way more problematic than the problem itself....

Comment: while @post.id will send the id but how to collect in my update controller and how to manipulate it like i have to check which button was click whether it was approve or decline and then do respective action

Comment: if its your first time with rails.. I'd recommend you to follow instructions of  some comprehensive tutorial either text based or may be a video.. [mackenziechild 12in12](https://mackenziechild.me/12-in-12/) are some pretty good hands on small application dev examples... go over anyone of them.. you'll get the idea how rails works..

Comment: i was following mackenzie child tutorial only ...i was facing some problem thats why i posted over here

Comment: can you share your `routes.rb` file? or if you have a public git repo for this please link me to that..

Comment: yes i can share my routes.rb file and I am updating my code

Comment: I have updated my code and now I have remove those 2 links from my edit section and move to show section there I am facing some problem.LIke I am able to send id but not able to send params[:commit ] to my edit section ..

Comment: dude that's Post model (`post.rb`)... I asked you for `routes.rb`.... that's inside the `config` folder... like `APPLICATION_ROOT_FOLDER/config/routes.rb`

Comment: sorry i actually made mistake .... now i have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems with your code.. I'll not try to address them all but the specific problem you are facing..

first you need to generate path for both `approve` and `decline` action..

```
resources :posts do
   patch '/approve' => 'posts#approve', as: :approve #posts_approve_path(post) is the route helper for this
   patch '/decline' => 'posts#decline', as: :decline #posts_decline_path(post) is the route helper for this
   resources :comments
end
```

this will generate the required routes.

now inside your view wherever you want to approve and decline.

```
<%= link_to "approve",posts_approve_path(@post.id), method: :patch %>
<%= link_to "decline",posts_decline_path(@post.id), method: :patch %>
```

In your controller you need to modify find_params as the generated routes will pass `:posts_id` as the `:id` param.

```
def find_params
   id = params[:id] || params[:posts_id]
   Post.find(id)
end
```

Now in your controller add 2 new methods to implement the functionality.

```
def approve
   @post = find_params
   @post.update_attribute(:status, 'approved') if @post.present?
   redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: 'Post approved'
end

def decline
   @post = find_params
   @post.destroy if @post.present?
   redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: 'Post deleted'
end
```

Comment: the link_to which you have provided should i put it in my edit view or show view ??

Comment: though i tried something else to work but anyways thx for giving your time